# my NativeScript app dosent display the google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2, nativescript

here is my code :

https://github.com/jonny720/do-here-client/tree/master/do-here

i took the map component code from here :

https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/tree/master/ng-demo/app/map

the map component should display the google maps but nothing is shown.

*i installed google maps sdk, and setup the api key in the android platform.

its the first time i'm working with api in my app.
can someone light my eyes and tell me what is the problem?

Comment: You sure you are not missing and of the steps stated https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-google-maps-sdk and you have generated the api key from you google console and applied it to you app appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

The api key is missing and you should register custom element in main.ts file, and the 2 files to copy from the nativescript-google-map module were missing from your app folder 
 and as well as the key too.

I forked your repo and update the app, also created a .gitignore file to exclude unnecessary files and folder from repo.

I tested and it works fine.

You will have to update these files with your appropriate Google API key

```
> do-here/app/main.ts
> do-here/app/App_Resources/Android/values/nativescript_google_maps_api.xml
> do-here/app/App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/nativescript_google_maps_api.xml
```

and update this file to redirect all unauthorized access back to login page, changed it to test the map page

```
do-here/app/@shared/services/auth-guard.service.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

ok first thank you a lot  KielSoft

i solved it by typing in the cli :

tns tun android --clean

Comment: That is cool. Also I still think you should add a .gitignore file to your project to ignore node_modules, hooks, and platforms from your project, you may check in my PR